# New topbar - do you want colours to meet the rest of a page?

Tags: discussion

With Stylish plugin [for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome) and [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), you can turn that generic black into Drupal blue. Here is the code:

```
@-moz-document domain("drupal.stackexchange.com") {
  .topbar {
    background-color: #003151 !important;
  }

  .topbar .topbar-icon:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .profile-me:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a:hover {
    background-color: #004161 !important;
  }
}

@-moz-document domain("meta.drupal.stackexchange.com") {
  .topbar {
    background-color: #313131 !important;
  }

  .topbar .topbar-icon:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .profile-me:hover,
  .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a:hover {
    background-color: #484848 !important;
  }
}
```

Of course I'm looking for improvements. Per-site CSS changes [are not ruled out yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210102/new-top-bar-allow-user-colour-choices/210121?noredirect=1#comment673479_210121), so we as well may get ready for them. And even without, it would be nice to be able to have our site look good and be coloured consistently again on our own.

Comment: +1, Molot, But I think it is not possible, because of the logo, check this blog http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/?cb=1 and please read A Bigger, Blacker Bar

Comment: @Bala I linked to the comment that says it might be possible. Maybe. Some time in the future when things settle down. Keeping all bars really dark would meet the idea "to make it obvious you are on Stack Exchange". And even if not, meta is the best place I can think of to keep our versions of how it should / might look like ;)

Comment: I posted this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color